# В городе Хасавюрт или в городе Хасавюрте?

Tags: орфография

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно Администрация города Хасавюрта или Хасавюрт. Я живу в городе Хасавюрт или в Хасавюрте?

Answer (score 4):

Правильно: администрация города Хасавюрта,   я живу в городе Хасавюрте.

Розенталь:

"Названия городов, сел, деревень, поселков, усадеб, выраженные склоняемым существительным, **как правило**, согласуются в падеже с определяемым словом, например: в городе Москве, у города Смоленска, над городом Саратовом; в деревню Дюевку, через хутор Подбанку, в селе Ильинском".

Но: "Названия местечек, аулов, кишлаков, застав не согласуются с родовым наименованием, например: в местечке Ельск, недалеко от аула Арысыпай, в кишлаке Гилян".

Таким образом, не склоняются малоизвестные топонимы для обеспечения  точности их названия.

[Розенталь. XLIV. СОГЛАСОВАНИЕ ОПРЕДЕЛЕНИЙ И ПРИЛОЖЕНИЙ](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm)